# cannot get a promise after bindActionCreators in Redux

Tags: promise, redux, redux-thunk

I use react/redux to create an app.

I've a custom action creator to make an async request (I use redux-thunk).

```
export function loginAttempt(userData) {
  return dispatch => {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', userData.username);
    formData.append('password', userData.password);

    fetch('https://api.t411.ch/auth', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.respone = response;
        dispatch(loginError(error));
        throw error;
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
       dispatch(loginSuccess(data));
    });
  }
```

In my component, I use bindActionCreators to bind this method with dispatch :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import TorrentLayout from './TorrentLayout';

import * as LoginActions from '../actions/login'; // <---- it's where the code above is located
import * as SearchActions from '../actions/search'; 


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    login: state.login,
    searching: state.searching
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({...LoginActions, ...SearchActions}, dispatch);
}

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log('should be a promise');
    let foobar = this.props.loginAttempt({username: 'username', password:'password'});

    console.log(foobar); // <------ undefined

    // that I want to do
    this.props.loginAttempt({username: 'username', password:'password'}).then(() => {
        this.props.search(this.props.login.token, "mysearch");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
           <SearchBar {...this.props} />
           <TorrentLayout {...this.props}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to apply 'then' to my action creator already bound to dispatch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return fetch()` inside your arrow function inside `loginAttempt`.  Like so:

```
export function loginAttempt(userData) {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch('https://api.t411.ch/auth', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }).then(...);
  }
```

Basically when you call your binded action creator the arrow functions gets executed but it doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'm doing all the logic inside the dispatcher, so I passed to it a done callback.

In my component, I'm calling the action login as follow

```js
login(values, setErrors, (user) => {
    console.log('done:', user)
})
```

then on my action, I do all the async calls, then call done(data) at the end

```js
export const login = (form: ILoginForm, setErrors, done) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
    // ....
    done(data)
}
```